# Facebook Comment in local machine or Phone (Hybrid Apps)

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have **read a lot of questions** here about including the facebook comment on hybrid mobile app (cordova app). I have the same issue and I don't get any concrete answer or solution. I also tried contacting facebook to report this issue. Their answer is:

> I'm afraid we can't provide that type of implementation assistance here: my understanding is that the plugin will only work when included on a http:// or https:// resource (and it may have issues if that resource is not publicly accessible). There's no officially supported way to do so, unfortunately.

So it means that when the html file is not hosted online the comment plugin won't work at all.

Now, I tried to make an html for facebook comment plugin. I try running it locally on my machine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-width="500" data-numposts="5"></div>

<style>
    .fb-comments{
    border:1px solid;
    min-height:500px;

    /*background:#000;*/
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

You may copy it and try also to run locally .

> (e.g: file:///C:/Users/....index.html)

I just notice that it has data, and it shows the comment box when the page loads then suddenly hides. Why is it like that?

**To all developers and programmers** here, Is there a possible solution here? running the html file locally and showing up the hidden comment box?